# Launch gulp task from a backend php/angularjs

Tags: php, html, angularjs, gulp

I'm a newbie with Gulp, I made a some custom tasks and would like to launch any task from any HTML, PHP, AngularJS application.

Is it possible? I try to find some feature at Google but I can't look nothing about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gulp is mainly meant to run as a development tool. You usually run some tasks during build or pre-deploy.

Having said that, it is possible to run gulp from php just as any external process, using [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), provided that your node or nvm environment is properly setup.

To execute gulp directly from within php is something probably unable to do as gulp requires node.js.

Comment: Yesssssssssss @Wtower.